# Search inside a range of fields MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, range, document, nosql

I have a DB on MongoDB, with a collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a64b4cfb80146432aff6ac"),
    "name": "Mid Range",
    "end" : NumberLong("50000"),
    "start" : NumberLong("10000"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59a64b4cfb80146432aff6ac"),
    "name": "Hi Range",
    "end" : NumberLong("100000"),
    "start" : NumberLong("150000"),
}
```

The user enters a number to validate: 125000, i need a query to get: "Hi Range" document.
How can i do that? I'm trying to avoid code side, but if there is no choice it's ok.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could even make do without the $and. You just need to set the query to find a result such that your number is less than or equal to its end and greater than or equal to its start. For example:

```
db.collection.find({start: {$lte: 125000}, end: {$gte: 125000}})
```

Note: Careful, if you want that range to include the start and end number, use [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/), [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/). Using $lt or $gt will not include it.

Comment: This works perfect! I think i was thinking a more complicated way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

```
db.find({name:/Hi Range/}) // regular Expression.
```

Comment: This is not the case, i need to search inside the min and max range, not literally the document name.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid logic that determine that 12500 is Hi Range you could do something like this

```
db.collection.find( { $and: [ { start: { $lte: 125000 } }, { end: { $gt: 12500 } } ] } )
```

Comment: I tried that, but i did not get the result. @Rafael Moreno answer works fine, and is almost the same, but without the explicit `$and`

Comment: Fair enough. It didn't work because I mixed up start and end since I assumed start was less than end. Changed that now.